# Adding Spraymalt

Tags: bottling

When adding spraymalt (instead of brewing sugar) to the filling bottle stage,

I found the first few bottles were easy as spooning the spraymalt into them,

then found the spraymalt powder was starting to congeal on the spoon and in around

the funnel, so making this a hard task.

Is there a better way of entering the spraymalt into the bottles ?

Answer (score 7):

[Compute](http://www.brewersfriend.com/beer-priming-calculator/) the total amount of spraymalt required to carbonate your entire batch of beer. Dissolve that amount of spraymalt in a cup or two of water to create your priming solution. Boil it briefly to sanitize. Allow it to cool. Pour it into your bottling bucket. Rack the beer onto it.

Personally, I find that giving the entire batch a *gentle* stir at this point helps to evenly distribute the priming sugar throughout. Others refuse to do this for fear of oxygen exposure. I've never had that problem.

If you don't use a bottling bucket, then add the priming solution directly to the beer vessel and give it a gentle stir.

http://www.homebrewing.org/How-to-Bottle-Beer_ep_34-1.html

Comment: My method is similar. I pour my spraymalt into a sanitized plastic bottle, followed by about half a litre of hot water (cooled from boiling), tighten the lid and give it a few shakes until fully dissolved, then pour into bottling bucket, then add the wort and proceed to bottling. No problem encountered while doing this for over 4 years.